# (Beginner) Java program skipping lines of code

Tags: java

I am currently working on a date difference program for school, and I cannot figure out why it entirely skips over the "secondMonth" input. It prints out the final lines but will only accept input for the "secondYear" and breaks the program. I wrote the program in Eclipse and I am compiling it within Eclipse. Any help would be very much appreciated.

My code:

```
if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("janurary"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 1;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("february"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 2;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("march"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 3;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("april"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 4;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("may"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 5;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("june"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 6;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("july"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 7;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("august"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 8;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("september"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 9;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("october"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 10;
}
else if (secondMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("november"))
{
    secondMonthNumber = 11;
}
else
{
    secondMonthNumber = 12;
}


System.out.print("Enter year: ");
secondYear = scan.nextInt();


System.out.print("These dates are " + (firstYear - secondYear) + "years and " + (firstMonthNumber - secondMonthNumber) + "months apart.");
```

Comment: Your program ends after you input your second month that's why. If you want more inputs ask for it.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you've written it to do. Where do you think it goes after `secondMonth =`? Your code doesn't do anything that would ask for more input. It just ends after that line executes.

Comment: it works the way you programmed it. java executes the statements one by one  in `main` from the beginning of the function till end. There are no loops or other programming stuff, so it just finishes when all is done.

Comment: and, btw, it is not python, so indentation plays no role there.

Comment: When I compile and run the program, it will not let me enter a value for the secondMonth. It terminates before I can input anything.

Comment: After `nextInt`, there's still a newline character in the buffer, so `nextLine` returns immediately and your program exists

Comment: *I cannot figure out why it entirely skips over the "secondMonth" input.* You're not showing that part in your code.

Answer (score -3):

Are you trying to add a loop in your code? You can either make it go on forever (while loop) or you can code a for loop (it'll go on a set amount of times).

```
public static void main(String args[]){

   while(true){

   /*enter code in here *\

   }

}
```

You could make an Arraylist so you can save the information you get from the user when it scans the users input.

or...

You could add a for loop (can only work x amount of times (named times in the example)).

```
//declare pvsm up here
//create a stationary array
int[] dates = new int[times];
for(int x  = 0; x < times; x++){

   dates[x] = /*information you are trying to load *\
}
```

Comment: You might want to look up how to load values into an Arraylist - pyth12

Comment: I am trying to enter a value for "secondMonth," but for some reason the program wont let me. This is causing issues for the rest of my code because it entirely skips the "secondMonth" step. It's supposed to continue on to this:

Comment: too many characters, I'll add it to the above code.

Comment: You call `nextLine()` once more after `nextInt()` to wait for next input.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with Daniel's program.